# Get empty columns in laravel collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this Laravel collection, obtained from a DB query:

```
$c = collect(\DB::connection('mysql_scipg')
     ->table('producao_email')
     ->where('cod_cliente', $cliente_id)
     ->where('lote',$lote)
     ->whereIn('cod_status',$statusCliente)
     ->select('dominio','lote','sv_email','cod_status')
     ->get());
```

The problem i'm encountering is, getting data from the collection, in cases where sv_email is different of "":

example:

there are cases where sv_email is filled in and cases where sv_email = "", sv email is either with information or "", note is not null, it is " ";

in the image below, I presented a case where sv_email = ""

using the command:

```
dd ($c-> where ('sv_email', '')
```

[collection where sv_email = ""](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJt80.png)

I tested the command dd($c->where('sv_email','SVV095')

[collection where sv_email != ""](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ2jb.png)

**the problem occurs when I try to get sv_email, in cases where it is different from ""**

I tested:

```
    dd($c->where('sv_email','<>',"");
    dd($c->where('sv_email','<>','');
    dd($c->where('sv_email','!=',"");
    dd($c->where('sv_email','!=','');
```

all returned an empty collection.

there is a case where it returns as I wish. But I have to do another query, and I don't want this way, because I would have to do 2 queries in the DB to get the data, and I can manipulate the collection, where am I going wrong?

the case where it works would be:

```
    $c_2 = collect(\DB::connection('mysql_scipg')
           ->table('producao_email')
           ->where('cod_cliente', $cliente_id)
           ->where('lote',$lote)
           ->where('sv_email','!=','')
           ->select('dominio','lote','sv_email','cod_status')
           ->get());
```

Comment: Sidenote, you don't need to wrap `DB::connection() ... ->get()` with a `collect()` call; `->get()` returns a Collection. This doesn't appear to matter though, but is an extra call you don't need.

Comment: This code works fine for me. `$c_2 = collect([101244=>["dominio"=>"gmail.com","lote"=>748,"sv_email"=>"","cod_status"=>"B"], 100370=>["dominio"=>"gmail.com","lote"=>748,"sv_email"=>"SVV095","cod_status"=>"B"]])->where("sv_email", "!=", "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way please:

```
$results = \DB::connection('mysql_scipg')
     ->table('producao_email')
     ->where('cod_cliente', $cliente_id)
     ->where('lote',$lote)
     ->whereIn('cod_status',$statusCliente)
     ->select('dominio','lote','sv_email','cod_status')
     ->get();

$filledEmailResults = $results->filter(function($value) {
    return !empty($value['sv_email']);
});
```

note that `->get()` method in eloquent returns collection and there is no need to convert the result to the collection by passing it to the `collect()` method